# Drawing dynamic line between 2 svg rects

Tags: javascript, svg

I've [this](https://jsfiddle.net/kfjp13xz/) code to draw 2 svg, with flexibility to adjust each rect starting and ending points from the shown input fileds.

Can I draw a line from the end of the top rect to the beginig of the bottom rect, so that this line keep connecting the 2 rect even if their position had been adjusted using the inputs fields above.

```js
let svgRect;

function xStart(XS){
  svgRect.setAttribute('x',XS)
}
function rWidth(RW){
  svgRect.setAttribute('width',+RW)
}
       
       
let svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
        svg.setAttribute("class", "octicon octicon-star");
      //  svg.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 14 16");
        svg.setAttribute("version", "1.1");
        svg.setAttribute("width", 240);
        svg.setAttribute("height", 160);
        svg.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true");
        let barThickness = 20

        let orders = [100, 152];
        //orders.forEach((element, index, array) => console.log('a[' + index + '] = ' + element) )
        orders.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
            console.log('a[' + index + '] = ' + element)
            let r = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
            r.setAttribute("x", 0);
            r.setAttribute("y",(barThickness+10)*index+0);
            r.setAttribute("width", element);
            r.setAttribute("height", barThickness);
            r.setAttribute("fill","black");

            let isDrawing = false;
            let x = element
            let mousePosition = 0

            r.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
                r.setAttribute("fill","red")
            });

            r.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => {
                r.setAttribute("fill","black")
                if (isDrawing === true) {
                    isDrawing = false;
                }
            });


            r.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
            svgRect = r
                isDrawing = true;
               // console.log(e.path[0])
                document.querySelector('#from').value = r.getAttribute('x') //e.path[0].getAttribute("x")
                document.querySelector('#to').value = r.getAttribute('width') // e.path[0].getAttribute("width")
            });

            r.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
                if (isDrawing === true) {
                    document.querySelector('#from').value = r.getAttribute('x') //e.path[0].getAttribute("x")
                document.querySelector('#to').value = r.getAttribute('width') // e.path[0].getAttribute("width")
                    
                    if(e.offsetX>mousePosition) {
                        x++
                    } else if(e.offsetX < mousePosition){
                        x--
                    }
                    mousePosition = e.offsetX
                    r.setAttribute("width", x)
                }
            });

            r.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
                if (isDrawing === true) {
                    document.querySelector('#from').value = r.getAttribute('x') //e.path[0].getAttribute("x")
                    document.querySelector('#to').value = r.getAttribute('width') // e.path[0].getAttribute("width")
                    isDrawing = false;
                }
            });

            svg.appendChild(r);
            document.body.appendChild(svg) 
        
        }  )
```

```html
<div>
   <label for="from">From:</label>
        <input onchange="xStart(this.value)" type="number" id='from' name="from">
        <label for="to">To:</label>
        <input onchange="rWidth(this.value)" type="number" id='to' name="to">
        <br><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```js
let svgRect;

function xStart(XS) {
  svgRect.setAttribute('x', XS)
  
  if(svgRect === rfirst) {
    line.setAttribute("x1", parseFloat(XS) + orders[0]);
  } else {
    line.setAttribute("x2", XS);
  }
}

function rWidth(RW) {
  svgRect.setAttribute('width', +RW)
  
  if(svgRect === rfirst) {
    line.setAttribute("x1", RW);
  }
}


let svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
svg.setAttribute("class", "octicon octicon-star");
//  svg.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 14 16");
svg.setAttribute("version", "1.1");
svg.setAttribute("width", 240);
svg.setAttribute("height", 160);
svg.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true");
let barThickness = 20
let rfirst;

let orders = [100, 152];
//orders.forEach((element, index, array) => console.log('a[' + index + '] = ' + element) )

let line = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "line");
line.setAttribute("x1", orders[0]);
line.setAttribute("x2", 0);
line.setAttribute("y1", barThickness*0.5);
line.setAttribute("y2", (barThickness*1.5 + 10));
line.setAttribute("stroke-width", "5");
line.setAttribute("stroke", "green");


orders.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
  console.log('a[' + index + '] = ' + element)
  let r = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
  r.setAttribute("x", 0);
  r.setAttribute("y", (barThickness + 10) * index + 0);
  r.setAttribute("width", element);
  r.setAttribute("height", barThickness);
  r.setAttribute("fill", "black");
  
  if(index === 0) {
    rfirst = r;
  };

  let isDrawing = false;
  let x = element
  let mousePosition = 0

  r.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
    r.setAttribute("fill", "red")
  });

  r.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => {
    r.setAttribute("fill", "black")
    if (isDrawing === true) {
      isDrawing = false;
    }
  });


  r.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
    svgRect = r
    isDrawing = true;
    // console.log(e.path[0])
    document.querySelector('#from').value = r.getAttribute('x') //e.path[0].getAttribute("x")
    document.querySelector('#to').value = r.getAttribute('width') // e.path[0].getAttribute("width")
  });

  r.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    if (isDrawing === true) {
      document.querySelector('#from').value = r.getAttribute('x') //e.path[0].getAttribute("x")
      document.querySelector('#to').value = r.getAttribute('width') // e.path[0].getAttribute("width")

      if (e.offsetX > mousePosition) {
        x++
      } else if (e.offsetX < mousePosition) {
        x--
      }
      mousePosition = e.offsetX
      r.setAttribute("width", x)
      
      if(r === rfirst) {
        line.setAttribute("x1", r.getAttribute('width'));
      }
    }
  });

  r.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
    if (isDrawing === true) {
      document.querySelector('#from').value = r.getAttribute('x') //e.path[0].getAttribute("x")
      document.querySelector('#to').value = r.getAttribute('width') // e.path[0].getAttribute("width")      
      isDrawing = false;
    }
  });

  svg.appendChild(r);

})

svg.appendChild(line);
document.body.appendChild(svg)
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="from">From:</label>
  <input onchange="xStart(this.value)" type="number" id='from' name="from">
  <label for="to">To:</label>
  <input onchange="rWidth(this.value)" type="number" id='to' name="to">
  <br><br>
</div>
```

The line is fairly simple to use for this because [only a simple attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/SVG/Element/line#attributes) (e.g. `x1` or `x2`) needs to be updated at any one time. Draw the initial line, then update it on `mousemove` of the rects and `onchange` of the inputs. It may be better to have the line under the rectangles so that it does not interrupt mouse events on them (for this, append the line before the rects).